# Change behavior of a Leaflet class via include()

Tags: javascript, leaflet

You can change the behavior of a Leaflet.js class by [including a mixin](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#class-include).

The tutorial [Extending Leaflet: Class Theory](http://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-1-classes.html#lclassinclude) says:

> If a class is already defined, existing properties/methods can be redefined, or new ones can be added by using .include():

However when attempting to do this, I get a `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error.

```js
var DemoClass = L.Class.extend({
  value: 42,
  demoMethod: function() {
    return this.value;
  }
});

DemoClass.include({
  demoMethod: function() {
    return DemoClass.prototype.demoMethod.call(this) * 2;
  },
  secondMethod: function() {
    return this.value;
  }
});

var instance = new DemoClass();
console.log("value=" + instance.value);
console.log("secondMethod()=" + instance.secondMethod());
console.log("demoMethod()=" + instance.demoMethod()); // gives a call stack exceeded
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
```

If it's relevant, the actual code is overriding `L.Marker.onAdd()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to isolate the base function:

```js
var DemoClass = L.Class.extend({
  value: 42,
  demoMethod: function() {
    return this.value;
  }
});

DemoClass.include({
  baseDemoMethod: DemoClass.prototype.demoMethod,
  demoMethod: function() {
    return this.baseDemoMethod() * 2;
  },
  secondMethod: function() {
    return this.value;
  }
});

var instance = new DemoClass();
console.log("value=" + instance.value);
console.log("secondMethod()=" + instance.secondMethod());
console.log("demoMethod()=" + instance.demoMethod());
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
  demoMethod: function() {
    return DemoClass.prototype.demoMethod.call(this) * 2;
  },
```

You're making an infinite recursive call, right there.

JS is weird sometimes, and this time is one of those. By referring to `DemoClass.prototype`, you are referring to the *latest state* of `DemoClass.prototype`... so `DemoClass.prototype.demoMethod` is referring to *itself*.

Whenever you overwrite a prototype method or property, the previous one gets [de-referenced and potentially garbage-collected](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management).

If you want to refer to the previous definition of the method, **you must keep a reference to the previous definition of the method**.

This usually requires some trickery in the form of a [JS closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work#111111) (keeping a reference to the original value in some controlled variable scope). There are a variety of ways to do this: keep a reference to the previous prototype as a class property, like @Jaws does; do a closure somewhere; do a [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript#8228308) like in [Leaflet.GridLayer.FadeOut](https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.GridLayer.FadeOut/blob/master/Leaflet.GridLayer.FadeOut.js), or anything that lets you keep a reference to the original method definition.